# Create Table using Highcharts GWT

Tags: gwt, highcharts

I am creating charts using GWT (Highcharts-1.7.0.jar) APIs.
I would also like to create tables for the corresponding chart data.
When I explored, I found 
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/export-data/showtable/
The following javascript will enable the table

```
    exporting: {
       showTable: true
    }
```

But I am not able to find this API in 'highcharts-1.7.0.jar'

I can implement custom logic for this.But I am using Drill Down APIs hence I want the table also to be loaded according to the Drilled Down Chart.

I have tried by set export as true

```
    chart.setExporting( new Exporting().setEnabled( true ) );
```

Upon adding this code I have got option to export as pdf,image etc., but not csv,xls.

Comment: Hi @user2699067, Similar to your second [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56577678/how-to-achieve-drill-up-back-to-chart-1-using-gwt-highcharts), I advise you to contact directly with the autors of GWT Highcharts: https://sourceforge.net/p/gwt-highcharts/discussion/general/

Answer (score 0):

In the jsfiddle example you provided, you can see that there is an option in the Highcharts configuration object:

```
exporting: {
   showTable: true
}
```

Moreover, as explained in the [Highcharts export documentation](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview), you need to add this to your code:

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<!-- optional -->
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/offline-exporting.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div class="chart-outer">
    <div id="container"></div>
    <!-- data table is inserted here -->
</div>
```

I also encourage you to take a look at the [exporting API documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting).

Comment: Thanks Lafarie,
I see 'showTable: true' will enable the table, But
I am not able to find this 'showtable' API in 'highcharts-1.7.0.jar'.
Please Note That :I am using 'GWT' not javascript.

Comment: Oh right, sorry about that @user2699067! I saw that `exporting` API is available from `Highcharts 2.0.0`. I think you need to upgrade your version a little bit (the latest is currently the `7.1.2`).